# Retrieve a html document from google docs - no api

Tags: php, google-docs

I would like to use google docs as a file server for a website, so I need to get and display html documents from gdocs with PHP-- but without the gdocs api. I found a way to list the documents with curl, but have no idea to get their contents.
Is that possible? And if it is, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not use an API for this?

Comment: I want to eat soup, but without a spoon. How can I do that?

Comment: @Pekka Because I read that I needed to upload zend to my server, and it's 50mo, more than what I can use for this website.

Juhana someone told me the same thing when I asked for listing files. It was possible.

Comment: @evuez you can use Zend Framework's components separately, there's no need to upload the whole thing. There is definitely no sane way of doing this without communicating with the API somehow.

Comment: @Pekka Oh great! I didn't hear about that before, I'm going to take a look at that--I can't upload more than 10mo (tiny, really tiny), do you think it will be sufficient for the needed component?

Comment: @evuez I'm not 100% sure, but I think it should. (10 MB is really little nowadays, though - if you are *paying* for that space, you're probably being ripped off. I pay €9/month for *50 Gigabytes*)

Comment: @Pekka Okay thanks! (I don't pay for that space, a friend is lending me some space on its server, but it is totally overloaded with my friend's files--that I can not remove of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use only a 2Mb folder with a zend component (Gdata) to extract info from gdocs spreadsheats, so yes, with less than 10mb I think it is possible.

I dont know if you will need some more component of zend for your project. This is the website from where I got this information and found the Gdata component: [LINK](http://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/php-interacting-wit-google-spreadsheet-using-zend-gdata/)

Best Regards.

PS: Maybe I am a little late for this answer but hope it helps somebody like it helped me.